# travis-ci cannot build .net project

Tags: c#, .net, travis-ci

I just pushed a test project for travis to build, but it fails. Error:

> ConsoleHelpersTests.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   `VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace`Microsoft'. Are you
>   missing an assembly reference?

my .travis.yml file:

```
language: csharp
solution: TravisDotNet.sln
```

Am I missing something?